# Time units of "mosek.dparam.optimizer_max_time"?

Tags: mosek

What is the unit of [mosek.dparam.optimizer_max_time](https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/pythonapi/parameters.html#mosek.dparam.optimizer_max_time) parameter. I mean does it expect the input value in: **seconds / milliseconds**?

Would it be safe to assume the time unit is always seconds, wherever the documentation does not explicitly specify (eg. [mosek.dparam.mio_max_time](https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/pythonapi/parameters.html#mosek.dparam.mio_max_time) , ...) ?

Comment: Time in Mosek is always wall time in seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Does the same holds for [mosek.iparam.license_pause_time](https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/pythonapi/parameters.html#mosek.iparam.license_pause_time) since the description use the term *milliseconds*?

Comment: I should have added "unless explicitly specified otherwise". Sorry. In any case all the optimization related times are in seconds. License pause may be the only one that is different.

Comment: Don't worry! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The unit is in seconds (s).

This is documented here from CVXPY documentation: https://docs.mosek.com/latest/faq/faq.html#cvxpy